# Convert Java.Util.HashMap to System.Collections.IDictionary

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

In Xamarin I've got a .jar I've imported using a Java Binding Library. One of the callbacks has a `Java.Lang.Object` parameter which gives me `Java.Util.HashMap` and `Java.Util.ArrayList` at runtime. I'm abstracting this SDK behind a cross-platform interface, so I need to convert this to a .NET type. It there anything like the `ArrayAdapter` except in reverse that can convert the Java types to their .NET equivalents?

For example, a binding class for a Java class called `RemoteCallback` might be used like this:

```
public MyRemoteCallback : RemoteCallback
{
    public void OnComplete(Java.Lang.Object result)
    {
        // At runtime, result is a graph of nested Java.Util.ArrayList 
        // and Java.Util.HashMap instances. This value is used in an 
        // implementation of a cross-platform interface, so I need to 
        // convert these to their .NET equivalent IEnumerable and 
        // IDictionary instances.
    }
}
```

At the moment I've got a working but rather inelegant solution. Xamarin provides the conversion in the opposite direction for the express purpose of providing parameters to Java libraries, it seems like this would be a natural mapping to provide as well, but I haven't found it.

Comment: Please provide some code and show where you are facing a problem.